# windows remote desktop options greyed out/disabled and set to allow remote desktop connections

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Recently i noticed that my windows 10 remote desktop option is permanently enabled and I am not able to disable it. 
please take a look at the image if any can point out what could be wrong it would be much appreciated, And thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you on a domain joined machine? Maybe your administrator does not want to allow remote connections...

Comment: Yes the PC is joined to domain. Recently couple people left the office. Maybe they enabled it under domain setting somewhere   I have full control over domain controller. But the thing is it's enabled to allow Remote Desktop connection.  I want to remove this setting from the AD. I checked and removed group policy and ran gpupdate and restart the PC but this setting still remains the same.

Comment: @cdavid after some digging around found that there was group policy which was set and removed. now those setting is stuck in PC for ever, as remove group policy from ad does not restore the PC side setting to default it was before.

Comment: Have you tried to do a `gpupdate /force` ? The other alternative is to set the GP again on AD and the propagate it to this machine.

Comment: Tried but it does not restore the old setting.

Answer (score 0):

Access the registry key `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` and modify the value of `fDenyTSConnections` to `0`.

Then restart your PC.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: This is an ancient question, but thanks for answering after so many years :)